# Rails with Sunspot add Child Model Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, sunspot-rails

So, I have been messing with this for hours and I think I have tried everything thats been posted on this issue already. This is my first question.

So, I am trying to search for models (Locations) :branch_name, :branch_address1, etc with their Child Model (Employees) :first_name used within that model as its own attribute. So the desired effect would be Locations (as results) would return if a locations employee name is in the Search Query. I'm trying to achieve this with code like this:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :partner
  has_many :employees, dependent: :destroy

  validates_presence_of :branch_name, :branch_address1, :branch_country, :branch_zip_code
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :employees, allow_destroy: true, :reject_if > proc { |attributes| attributes['first_name'].blank? }

  searchable do
    text :branch_name, :branch_address1, :branch_city, :branch_zip_code
    text :employee_attributes do
      :first_name
      if :employee_attributes
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I would like to also use the parent model (Partners) Name but, I couldn't get that to work either.

Could I make a new column in the Locations table to capture every new employee name, or can I search within that models children?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used solr with rails, I had encountered similar problems.
Like you asked about new column, I had added a new field to solr

> pseudo code

```
searchable do
 text :first_name, :stored => true
 string  :partner_name, :stored => true do
   partner.name
 end
end
```

Please note, stored fields increase cost.

In my case, I had to fire multiple queries that took 47 seconds, storing value helped me avoid multiple queries, single query took 5 seconds.

You need to re-index to get results.

Comment: I still end up getting this code when I re-index. Is there anything else I should be changing in my application?  `NoMethodError: undefined method 'first_name' for #<Location:0x007ff308e03528>`

Comment: I also went ahead and used the ideas in that approach to try things like `string :employees_first_name, :stored => true do
      employees.first_name
    end `  with similar issues: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'first_name' for #<Employee`